# Could anyone help me figure out the problem in this C code?

Tags: c

Could anyone tell me the problem with my program? it is a program in C to find the number of Armstrong number between 1 and 500. I am a beginner in programming, thus would be open to learning.

```
      #include <stdio.h>
        int main()
        {
        int number,originalNumber,remainder,result=0;
        number = 001;
        while (number <= 500)
        {
        originalNumber=number;
        while(originalNumber != 0)
        {
            remainder= originalNumber%10;
            result += remainder*remainder*remainder;
            originalNumber /= 10;
        }
        if (result==number)
        {
            printf("%d is a Armstrong Number",number);
        }
        number++;
        }


}
```

Comment: Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values the problem should become quite obvious.

Comment: Usually the person asking the question has a problem they want help with. Do you want us to guess what the problem is, or what is the actual issue? Please clarify the question, for example, “this code should do X, but at the moment it does Y instead/fails with input Z/crashes at point Q/something else”

Comment: Not related to the actual problem, but if you assign a number with a prefixed `0` like in `number = 001;`, then that's an octal literal. It doesn't make a difference in this case, but if for instance you wrote `010`, then you only get `8`, so be careful with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me the problem with my program?

The problem is that `result=0` is only initialized at the start of the program, while `result` must be set to 0 in each `while (number <= 500)` loop cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set reset `result` before entering the `while(originalNumber != 0) { ... }` loop. To prevent such easy mistakes, it is a good idea to define variables in the innermost block possible. If the content of a variable does not have to be "remebered" after exiting a block, you define the variable inside that block. (A block beeing the code between `{` and `}`)

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* changed `int main()` to `int main(void)` */
int main(void)
{

    for(int number = 1;  number<= 500; number++)
    {
        /*
          `number` has to be remebered each time we exit and reenter 
          this block, so we have to declare it outside.

          `orginalNumber` and `result` can be "forgot" after each time we finish
           this block so we declare them here
           (Just remember that each iteration of the loop is an "entering" and
           "exiting" of this block) 
         */  
        int originalNumber = number;
        int result = 0;

        while(originalNumber != 0)
        {
            /*
              `remainder` can be "forgot" at the end of this block, so we
               declare it here
            */ 
            int remainder= originalNumber%10;
            result += remainder*remainder*remainder;
            originalNumber /= 10;
        }
        if (result==number)
        {
            /* Added a newline when printing */
            printf("%d is a Armstrong Number\n",number);
        }
    }
}
```